# Not recognizing tie in Tic Tac Toe AI

Tags: python

I am building a Tic Tac Toe AI. Here are the rules for the AI:

1. If there is a winning move, play it.
2. If the opponent has a winning move, block it.
3. Otherwise, play randomly.

Here's the code:

```
# main.py

# Prorities:
# - If there is a winning move, play it
# - If the opponent has a winning move, block it.
# - If nothing to block, make a random move.

import random
import time
import copy

boxes = []
for i in range(3):
  row = []
  for j in range(3):
    row.append(" ")
  boxes.append(row)

def printBoard():
  to_print = ""
  to_print += " " + boxes[0][0] + " | " + boxes[0][1] + " | " + boxes[0][2] + " \n"
  to_print += "---+---+---\n"
  to_print += " " + boxes[1][0] + " | " + boxes[1][1] + " | " + boxes[1][2] + " \n"
  to_print += "---+---+---\n"
  to_print += " " + boxes[2][0] + " | " + boxes[2][1] + " | " + boxes[2][2] + " \n"
  return to_print
  
turn = random.randint(1, 2)
if turn == 1:
  coin = "you (X)"
else:
  coin = "the AI (O)"

print("The coin flip shows", coin, "will go first!")
input("Press Enter to begin! ")

def checkWin(boxes):
  win = False
  who = " "
  for i in range(3):
    if boxes[i][0] == boxes[i][1] and boxes[i][1] == boxes[i][2]:
      who = boxes[i][0]
      if who != " ":
        win = True
  
  for i in range(3):
    if boxes[0][i] == boxes[1][i] and boxes[2][i] == boxes[1][i]:
      who = boxes[0][i]
      if who != " ":
        win = True
          
  if boxes[0][0] == boxes[1][1] and boxes[1][1] == boxes[2][2]:
    who = boxes[0][0]
    if who != " ":
      win = True
  if boxes[0][2] == boxes[1][1] and boxes[1][1] == boxes[2][0]:
    who = boxes[0][2]
    if who != " ":
      win = True
      
  return win, who
  
def checkTie(boxes):
  for row in boxes:
    for box in boxes:
      if box != "X" and box != "O":
        return False
  return True
  
def checkMove(boxes, player):
  for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
      if boxes[i][j] != "X" and boxes[i][j] != "O":
        boxCopy = copy.deepcopy(boxes)
        boxCopy[i][j] = player
        win, who = checkWin(boxCopy)
        if win:
          return True, i, j
  return False, 0, 0
      

while True:
  
  print("Check 1")
  win, who = checkWin(boxes)
  if win and who == "X":
    print("Player X has won.")
    print(" ")
    print(printBoard())
    break
  elif win and who == "O":
    print("Player O has won.")
    print(" ")
    print(printBoard())
    break
  elif checkTie(boxes) == True:
    print("It has been concluded as a tie.")
    break
  print("Check 2")
  
  if turn == 1:
    print("")
    print(printBoard())
    row = (int(input("Pick a row to play: ")) -1)
    col = (int(input("Pick a column to play: ")) -1)
    if ((row < 4 and row > -1) and (col < 4 and col > -1)) and (boxes[row][col] == " "):
      boxes[row][col] = "X"
      turn = 2
    else:
      print("Sorry, that is not allowed.")
      print(" ")

# Prorities:
# - If there is a winning move, play it
# - If the opponent has a winning move, block it.
# - If nothing to block, make a random move.
   
  else:
    print("")
    print(printBoard())
    print("[*] AI is choosing...")
    time.sleep(1)
    row = random.randint(0, 2)
    col = random.randint(0, 2)
    winMove, winRow, winCol = checkMove(boxes, "O")
    lossMove, lossRow, lossCol = checkMove(boxes, "X")
    if winMove and (boxes[winRow][winCol] != "X" and boxes[winRow][winCol] != "O"):
      boxes[winRow][winCol] = "O"
      turn = 1
      print("Statement 1: Win play")
    elif lossMove and (boxes[lossRow][lossCol] != "X" and boxes[lossRow][lossCol] != "O"):
      boxes[lossRow][lossCol] = "O"
      turn = 1
      print("Statement 2: Block play")
    elif boxes[row][col] != "X" and boxes[row][col] != "O":
      boxes[row][col] = "O"
      turn = 1
      print("Statement 3: Random play")
    else:
      print("Statement 4: None")
    print("Check 3")
```

The problem occurs when there is a tie. Either the function `checkTie()`, or the `if` statement isn't working. You might see a couple `print('Check #')` every once in a while. When you run the code and it's a tie, it shows all the checks going by. Which means it is passing through the check. When there is a tie, it just keeps doing the loop and repeating its turn but not making a move.

What is the mistake and how can I do this correctly?

Comment: Can you please tell us which inputs we have to give to the game so that we can see the problematic behaviour?

Comment: When you say "the `if` statement isn't working", which one are you referring to exactly? There are a lot of `if` statements in this code.

Comment: The if statement that checks if checkTie() returned True or not, inside the while loop. The user just inputs the row and column on their turn.

Answer (score 2):

I think your function should be

```py
def checkTie(boxes):
  for row in boxes:
    for box in row:
      if box != "X" and box != "O":
        return False
  return True
```

You mistyped ( I think) `boxes` for `row` in the second `for` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def checkTie(boxes):
    if any(" " in box for box in boxes):
        return False
    return True
```

Change your `checkTie` function to this

The rest is all good.

Comment: Why block instead of win? If it is your turn, and there is a winning move if you play that move you win. Winning ends the game which means the opponent can't win. I also don't see a difference in what you did for the function.